# Java scheduling each day

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, timertask

So i have tools that first the apps check in database, and then send an email. It is done. what problem for me is the scheduling. i already read some timer task. i need the tools to run every day at 00:00aam. For better or worst, here is my code

```
package SQLTest;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import SQLTest.EmailSender;


 public class TestSQL
 {

  public static void sQl(String datesec)
  {
  try
  {
  // create mysql database connection
  String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
  String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost;
  Class.forName(myDriver);
  String userName = dbuser;
  String pass = dbpass;
  String checkQa = "check it QA";
  String juDul = "blabla";
  String opcel1 = "opcel1 ";
  String opcel2 = "opcel2 ";
  String opcel3 = "opcel3 ";
  String opcel4 = "opcel4 ";
  String opcel5 = "opcel5 ";
  String opcel6 = "opcel6 ";
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
  Date time = (Date) calendar.getTime();
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String currentDate = dateFormat.format(time);
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, userName , pass );


 String query = "the query"



  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

  //java resultset
  while (rs.next())
  {

   int tanggal = rs.getInt("tanggal");


    // print the results
    System.out.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n");  

    if(column1 == 0) EmailSender.emailNotification(juDul+opcel1+currentDate, 
    "email Body " + "\n" + checkQa);
    }

  st.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
}


}
```

is it i have to make new class to handle the schedule?
are there some good example to pass my class (TestSQL) for the scheduling?

thanks in advance

EDIT: here is my scheduler class. i manage to pass it to this class.

```
package SQLTest;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



public final class Scheduler extends TimerTask{

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
TimerTask scheduletimer  = new Scheduler();

   //perform the task once a day at 00 a.m., starting tomorrow morning
   //(other styles are possible as well)
   Timer timer = new Timer();

   Timer t = new Timer();
   t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
       new TimerTask()
       {
           public void run()
           {

              System.out.print("========[ 3600 Second Passed ---> 1 Hour  ]=======\n");
           }
       },
       0,      // run first occurrence immediately
       3600000);

   System.out.println("scheduling ==> " + getTomorrowMorning00am());
   try{
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(scheduletimer, getTomorrowMorning00am(), fONCE_PER_DAY);
   }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("ERROR : " +e);
    }
 }

 /**
 * Implements TimerTask's abstract run method.
 */
 public void run(){
   //here is my class implementation
     System.out.print("===================================================\n");
     System.out.print("schedule Started");
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   Date date = new Date();
   String datesec = dateFormat.format(date);
  try {
   cal.setTime( dateFormat.parse(datesec));
   } catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  System.out.print("ERROR : " + e);
  }
  cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 0 );    
   datesec = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
   **TestSQL.sQl(datesec);**
   System.out.print("===================================================\n");
   System.out.print("scheduling ==> " + getTomorrowMorning00am());
   }

  // PRIVATE ////

  //expressed in milliseconds
  private final static long fONCE_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24 ;
  private final static int fONE_DAY = 1;
  private final static int fZERO_AM = 0;
  private final static int fZERO_MINUTES = 0;

  private static Date getTomorrowMorning00am(){
  Calendar tomorrow = new GregorianCalendar();
  tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, fONE_DAY);
  Calendar result = new GregorianCalendar(
  tomorrow.get(Calendar.YEAR),
  tomorrow.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  tomorrow.get(Calendar.DATE),
  fZERO_AM,
  fZERO_MINUTES
  );
  return result.getTime();
  }

  }
```

NOTE : Feel Free if someone got another ideas of my code. is it wrong, is it incomplete, or is it something else. keep share :D

Comment: You could also put the whole Java process into a cron job, and run it once a day.

Comment: actually i can make it happen. i updated the scheduler code for someone that needed. sorry if my code still bad. i'm still noob :D

Comment: @Nicolas  i m also in learning stage and want to set alarm time in alarm manager daily at specific time i.e 12:10Am can u pls help me how can i do this ? using Schedular

Comment: @Thilo, I wanted to ask this as a new question but might be marked as duplicate. What is the harm in using a **java.util.timer** as a crontab?

Comment: @YoungEmil: The Java timer will not fire when your Java app is not running. It will run multiple times if you have multiple instances of your app running. It will not (without you putting in extra code) keep an activity log or do retries. An external scheduling service is more robust that way.  On the plus side: fewer moving parts, if you app is still very small you may want to keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you @Thilo, this looks helpfup. Will keep it simple when the need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mix up the scheduling functionality with the task implementation. What you need is an API which allows you to schedule jobs that are to be executed at a given time. You can either:

- **Implement such an API yourself**. This can be very simple and straightforward: model an interface for a `Job` and implement a `Scheduler` which allows to schedule jobs for a given time, and polls for tasks that are due now (scheduled time <= current time) and executes them. This requires your scheduler to run along your application (separate thread). Depending on the environment (client, web container, application server) you need to hook into the lifecycle to start and terminate your scheduler.
- **Use an existing API** such as [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)
- Or, as *Thilo* said in the comment to your question: **make the job a standalone program and schedule it** with Cron (Linux/Unix) or Windows Scheduler.

Comment: actually i make another class for scheduler, and make it main class. so my scheduler class can use my sql class. look for my update question. thanks for your answer, i dont want to look for cron or another api. i just want to make it in java timer (because i'm still learning). thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a Cron Job (Scheduled Task) for your application

Cron is driven by a crontab (cron table) file, a configuration file that specifies shell commands to run periodically on a given schedule.

**Reference links:**

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
>
> http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml
>
> https://www.google.co.in/#q=cron+job+scheduling+steps

For the configured file provide a `.sh` file having below sample commands for running your application.

```
cd /home
java -cp ".:./jars/ojdbc14.jar:./jars/commons-logging.jar:./jars/j2ssh-ant-0.2.9.jar:"  -Xms512m -Xmx512m SQLTest.TestSQL
```

Comment: thanks, look for my updated question if you wanna take a look and correcting my code :D